# Building a Frequency Table of Run Lengths

Tags: r

```
 ID   Jan Feb  Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Nov Dec 
  1     0   0    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  2     1   1    1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
  3     0   0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  4     1   0    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  5     0   0    0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0
  6     1   1    1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I have this table, which I want to count the number of runs of 1 (consecutive runs of 1 across months) and get the following frequency table. I want to get the max run length for each row, for example in row 2, there are runs of length 3 and 1, so I will take only the run length 3 in the count.

```
 Runs   Freq
  1      1   
  2      1   
  3      2   
  4      0 
  5      1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'm not normally a fan of simple RTM type comments, but without seeing what you've tried so far and where you ran into issues, I think the best I'd say is see `help("apply")`, `help("max")`, `help("rle")`, and `help("table")`

Comment: The function `rle()` certainly is available in the `base` package in R 4.0.0; I'm running R 4.0.0 right now and it's there

Answer (score 0):

Good work; in the comments you got close to where you need to get. The only things you really still have left to do are:

1. `apply()` what you've done across the rows of the data frame. I've done this with a slightly altered form of what you came up with.
2. You may want to also wrap things in a little code to make a nicely formatted result like how you have in the question

Here's how I approached it:

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
ID   Jan Feb  Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Nov Dec
  1     0   0    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  2     1   1    1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
  3     0   0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  4     1   0    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  5     0   0    0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0
  6     1   1    1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0")
res <- data.frame(Runs = 0:nrow(dat))
tab <- table(apply(dat[,-1], 1, function(x) {
    RLE <- rle(x)
    if ( any(RLE$values == 1) ) {
        return(max(RLE$lengths[RLE$values == 1]))
    } else {
        return(0)
    }
}))
res <- merge(res, data.frame(Runs = names(tab), Freq = unclass(tab)), all.x = TRUE)
res[is.na(res)] <- 0
res
```

The result was

```
  Runs Freq
1    0    1
2    1    2
3    2    0
4    3    2
5    4    0
6    5    1
7    6    0
```

You can see this differs a little from the expected output you posted in the question, but manual inspection of the table (possible since it's a good, small example data set) seems to confirm this is the right answer.

Comment: @Eisen It may be hard to say without your data. This *can* happen as a result of memory limitations, though it's more often due to recursion issues. Is your data such that you could edit your question to include the output of the R command `dput(your_data)`?

Comment: Also I dont see any recursion here as well?

Comment: I tried to rerun your example again. I get the same C Stack Error.., but when I run it in a different project it works?

Comment: @Eisen This almost certainly has to do with some variable that you had defined in your global environment that somehow caused a memory or recursion issue. It would be hard to reproduce without your whole `.Rhistory`. If the code works in a fresh R session, then you shouldn't generally have problems

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` strategy

```r
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "ID   Jan Feb  Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Nov Dec 
  1     0   0    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  2     1   1    1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
  3     0   0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  4     1   0    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  5     0   0    0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0
  6     1   1    1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0")

library(tidyverse)

dat %>% rowwise() %>%
  transmute(Runs = {x <- rle(c_across(Jan:Dec)); y <- x$lengths[x$values == 1] ; ifelse(all(x$values != 1), 0, max(y))}) %>%
  table(dnn = list()) %>% as.data.frame() %>% complete(Runs = as.factor(0:12))
#> # A tibble: 13 x 2
#>    Runs   Freq
#>    <fct> <int>
#>  1 0         1
#>  2 1         2
#>  3 2        NA
#>  4 3         2
#>  5 4        NA
#>  6 5         1
#>  7 6        NA
#>  8 7        NA
#>  9 8        NA
#> 10 9        NA
#> 11 10       NA
#> 12 11       NA
#> 13 12       NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>